# Is there an aggregating service for online content distribution systems?

Tags: steam, origin, desura

I have bought games from a few online shops, like Steam, Desura, GoG, Origin, Battle.NET and probably a few others. It is annoying to know/remember where I bought each game, so I'm wondering if there is a program that can collect all the information about what/where I bought and present them in consistent manner.

Any ideas?

(I know I can add custom launchers to e.g. Steam, but the simply won't work if I don't have the games installed so that's not what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no service that has what you're asking for. Probably because it would be a huge undertaking. Just automatically listing all the games you own would require a lot of work, as most of the services don't have an API, actually running/installing games using a service like this would be a whole new nightmare of reverse engineering that would be practically impossible to maintain.

The best thing you could probably do is keep a list of your own.